# PowerShell script to decrypt file

Tags: command-line, encryption, powershell

Can some one help me with this command to decrypt files using powershell?

```
echo YOURpassPHRASE | gpg --keyring "C:\directory\filepath" --secret-keyring "C:\directory\filepath" --batch --yes --passphrase-fd 0 -o DesiredOutputFileName -d TargetEncryptedFile
```

What do the following options mean?

`--keyring "C:\directory\filepath"`

`--secret-keyring "C:\directory\filepath"`

Comment: Are you asking what keyring and secret-keyring do exactly?  They are used to validate other keys [manual](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual.htm)

Comment: @Ramhound Your link is 404 :/

Comment: @DavidPostill - I copied and pasted a google seach result.  Figures...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What do the following options mean?

```
--keyring "C:\directory\filepath"
--secret-keyring "C:\directory\filepath"
```

The options are documented in the [gnupg manual](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/GPG-Configuration-Options.html).

> 4.2.1 How to change the configuration
>
> These options are used to change the configuration and are usually
>   found in the option file.

...

> `--keyring file`
>
> Add file to the current list of keyrings. If file begins with a tilde
>   and a slash, these are replaced by the `$HOME` directory. If the
>   filename does not contain a slash, it is assumed to be in the GnuPG
>   home directory (`~/.gnupg` if `--homedir` or `$GNUPGHOME` is not
>   used).
>
> Note that this adds a keyring to the current list. If the intent is to
>   use the specified keyring alone, use `--keyring` along with
>   `--no-default-keyring`.
>
> `--secret-keyring file`
>
> This is an obsolete option and ignored. All secret keys are stored in
>   the `private-keys-v1.d` directory below the GnuPG home directory.

Source [GPG Configuration options](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/GPG-Configuration-Options.html)